# OpenCV: How do I implement "Keystone Correction"?

Tags: java, opencv

I want to take an image that is looking at a rectangle from below (creating a trapezoid) and change it into the original rectangle. For example, imagine you were on the ground taking a photograph of a skyscraper. I want to use that data to find what the side of the skyscraper looks like. How can I do that?

Keystone Correction normally refers to an offset projector, but that's not exactly what's happening. My source image is already messed up in the same way as an offset projector would make it. I need to get it straight-on.

Thanks for any help. If it matters I'm using the Java version of OpenCV, but I'm happy with any answers; I'm sure it's easy to make it into java from any other language.

Edit: I want to do what's shown for Notre Dame on this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called homography. You need to know the corners of the trapezoid and then compute the homography matrix by using findHomography function and then use warpPerspective function to generate the corrected image. I have written a simple python program for you to play around with and provided the result image so that you know what it does and see if that's what you are talking about.

[image]

code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import cv

pSrc = [(  98,67),( 331 ,  75),( 415 , 469),(  27 , 466)]
pDst = [(  27,67),( 415 ,  75),( 415 , 469),(  27 , 466)]
def srcMouse(event, x, y, flags,params):
    global pSrc
    if event == cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

        if len(pSrc) >=4:
            pSrc=[]
        pSrc.append((x,y))
        print np.array(pSrc,dtype=np.float32)

def dstMouse(event, x, y, flags,params):
    global pDst
    if event == cv.CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        if len(pDst) >=4:
            pDst=[]
        pDst.append((x,y))

cv2.namedWindow('src')
cv.SetMouseCallback('src', srcMouse, 0)
cv2.namedWindow('dst')
cv.SetMouseCallback('dst', dstMouse, 0)

im = cv2.imread('c:/data/notre.jpg')
dst = np.zeros(im.shape,dtype=np.uint8)
while(1):
    imD = im.copy()
    dstD = dst.copy()
    for p in pSrc:
        cv2.circle(imD,p,2,(255,0,0),-1)
    for p in pDst:
        cv2.circle(dstD,p,2,(255,0,0),-1)

    if len(pSrc)==4 and len(pDst)==4:
        H = cv2.findHomography(np.array(pSrc,dtype=np.float32),np.array(pDst,dtype=np.float32),cv2.LMEDS)
        dstD=cv2.warpPerspective(imD,H[0],(dstD.shape[1],dstD.shape[0]))
    cv2.imshow('src',imD)
    cv2.imshow('dst',dstD)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) ==27:
        exit(0)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to computer vision. What exactly is a homography?

Comment: Homography is a matrix that describe the relationship between two planes.In this case one is distorted by perspective projection and another is where it is corrected. `findHomography` computes this matrix(`H`) based on 4 points(minimum required), if there are more than 4 points, it will calculate a least square fitting that minimizes the reprojection error. `warpPerspective` perform mapping of original image pixels into the new plane described by this matrix. Please consult online sources for more detailed explanation(http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc2503/tutorials/homography.pdf)

Comment: @Zaw Lin, nice work! thanks for posting.


i am using Python 2.7.8 x64 + OpenCV 3.1.0 ( which seems to have fused with the older OpenCV API ). in any case, the code wouldn't run for me as is, so i fixed it up for my setup, and cleaned it up a bit, as well as having it dump the resulting homography matrix ( which i was interested in comparing to an alternative method for computing it ).


here's a link: https://gist.github.com/psydbernz/8d980e0f9f4a1530f2e1ecef4d1b5210